# mod_vhost_alias VirtualDocumentRoot many domains

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.2

I'm sure I'm not the first person to encounter this problem, but I cannot, for the life of me, find an answer - although that could be down to not knowing what to search.

I have the need to host many client websites on an Ubuntu server. All is working well, but I want to set up dynamic virtual hosts, so that I can automate the process of creating a wordpress site on the server. I've got `mod_vhost_alias` module working, and am pleased with that, however, I have ran into an issue with `.com` domains vs `.co.uk` or `.com.au` domains and the `VirtualDocumentRoot`

For a domain such as `example.com` I want all requests to `www.exapmple.com` and `example.com` to point to a directory called something like `/var/webroot/example.com` and for domains such as `example.co.uk`, I would like all requests to `www.example.co.uk` and `example.co.uk` to point to a directory called `/var/webroot/example.co.uk`

The VDR I have at the moment looks like this...

`VirtualDocumentRoot /var/webroot/%-2.0.%-1.0`

Which grabs the second to last and last parts. This works great for `example.com` but for `example.co.uk` it is looking for a directory at `/var/webroot/co.uk` - which is not ideal!

Is there a way around this? Do I need to use `mod_rewrite` and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where I'd just break out the symlinks instead of using a very specific (and potentially fragile) `RewriteRule`:

Use `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/webroot/%0`, then within `/var/webroot/` create a symlink for `www.example.com` pointing to the real directory of `example.com`.  This will work with domains however deep you need, in addition to being a little more flexible if you have a site where `www` should have different content for some reason, or you want to point `aaa.example.com` to the same content as `example.com`.

If that's not to your liking, then you could indeed use `mod_rewrite`:

```
DocumentRoot /var/webroot
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /%2/$1
```

That'll just always look for the domain name in `/var/webroot`, ripping the `www` off the front if it's there before looking.

Alternately, you could also redirect to remove (or add) the `www` to all requests instead of serving the same content for both domains.

Comment: I've gone with the rewrite option as this will work best for my requirements. Thanks for your help! :-)